# systemd-resolved change dns cname records

Tags: dns, systemd-networkd

I have a PC with Arch Linux (4.7.2-1-ARCH) on it. The PC uses DHCP to get its IP, but uses a different DNS Server that i configured via systemd-resolved. When I use the dig command with a domain the has a CNAME record, the associated A record is missing. If I use dig with the server manualy configured the A record is there. Any ideas why the systemd-resolved changes the dns records?

If you need any additional infos let me know.

Here is my network (systemd-networkd) configuration

```
[Match]
Name=ens18

[Network]
DNS=10.0.0.18
DHCP=ipv4

[DHCPv4]
UseHostname=false
UseDNS=false
```

resolv.conf:

```
# This is a static resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to
# systemd-resolved via its DNS stub listener on 127.0.0.53.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

dig api.pushbullet.com:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.4-P2 <<>> api.pushbullet.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 59038
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;api.pushbullet.com.        IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
api.pushbullet.com. 186 IN  CNAME   ghs-svc-https-c573.ghs-ssl.googlehosted.com.

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Son Sep 11 01:17:57 CEST 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 101
```

dig api.pushbullet.com@10.0.0.18:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.4-P2 <<>> api.pushbullet.com @10.0.0.18
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 33081
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 13, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;api.pushbullet.com.        IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
api.pushbullet.com. 184 IN  CNAME   ghs-svc-https-c573.ghs-ssl.googlehosted.com.
ghs-svc-https-c573.ghs-ssl.googlehosted.com. 282 IN A 72.14.247.65

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.           509182  IN  NS  j.root-servers.net.
.           509182  IN  NS  d.root-servers.net.
.           509182  IN  NS  a.root-servers.net.
.           509182  IN  NS  l.root-servers.net.
.           509182  IN  NS  g.root-servers.net.
.           509182  IN  NS  b.root-servers.net.
.           509182  IN  NS  m.root-servers.net.
.           509182  IN  NS  i.root-servers.net.
.           509182  IN  NS  f.root-servers.net.
.           509182  IN  NS  h.root-servers.net.
.           509182  IN  NS  e.root-servers.net.
.           509182  IN  NS  k.root-servers.net.
.           509182  IN  NS  c.root-servers.net.

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 10.0.0.18#53(10.0.0.18)
;; WHEN: Son Sep 11 01:17:59 CEST 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 328
```

Comment: Many people will recognize the question and ignore it to avoid wasting time trying to help you since you'll just remove it like you did last night.  Now take good note that **you are not asking for the A record**.  Try `dig a api.pushbullet.com` to get it.

Comment: @JuliePelletier what are you talking about. I did not remove anything. The output of dig command should be the same.

Comment: Sorry about that.  It wasn't deleted, it's cross-posted from http://serverfault.com/questions/802300/arch-cant-ping-some-cname-records

Answer (score 0):

Output of the dig command is different because it was a different command.

```
$ dig api.pushbullet.com @127.0.0.1

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;api.pushbullet.com.            IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
api.pushbullet.com.     12      IN      CNAME   ghs-svc-https-c573.ghs-ssl.googlehosted.com.
ghs-svc-https-c573.ghs-ssl.googlehosted.com. 300 IN A 72.14.247.65

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.                       495764  IN      NS      g.root-servers.net.
.                       495764  IN      NS      e.root-servers.net.
.                       495764  IN      NS      l.root-servers.net.
.                       495764  IN      NS      j.root-servers.net.
.                       495764  IN      NS      i.root-servers.net.
.                       495764  IN      NS      d.root-servers.net.
.                       495764  IN      NS      a.root-servers.net.
.                       495764  IN      NS      m.root-servers.net.
.                       495764  IN      NS      k.root-servers.net.
.                       495764  IN      NS      f.root-servers.net.
.                       495764  IN      NS      b.root-servers.net.
.                       495764  IN      NS      h.root-servers.net.
.                       495764  IN      NS      c.root-servers.net.

;; Query time: 72 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Son Sep 11 12:23:11 CEST 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 328
```

Comment: That doesn't show the `A` record.  You'd need to ask for it!